# C++ NamedPipeClientStream Send Data

Tags: c#, c++, pipe

I want to send data from a C++ DLL file via pipes to a C# pip server. The server is already programmed and getting data works fine with a C# client.

My simple C# client code:

```
        System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient = new System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream(".", "testpipe", System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection.InOut, System.IO.Pipes.PipeOptions.None);

        if (pipeClient.IsConnected != true) { pipeClient.Connect(); }

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeClient);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeClient);

            try
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Test Message");
                sw.Flush();
                pipeClient.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
        }
```

However, I don't get along realizing this client in C++. Which header files do I need?
Could you please give me a simple example? Thank you!

EDIT:
Thanks for your reply!
To test it, I created a C++ program and compiled now the following:

```
        #include "stdafx.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
HANDLE pipe = CreateFile(
    L"testpipe",
    GENERIC_READ, // only need read access
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL
);

if (pipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    // look up error code here using GetLastError()
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    system("pause");
    return 1;
}


// The read operation will block until there is data to read
wchar_t buffer[128];
DWORD numBytesRead = 0;
BOOL result = ReadFile(
    pipe,
    buffer, // the data from the pipe will be put here
    127 * sizeof(wchar_t), // number of bytes allocated
    &numBytesRead, // this will store number of bytes actually read
    NULL // not using overlapped IO
);

if (result) {
    buffer[numBytesRead / sizeof(wchar_t)] = '?'; // null terminate the string
   // wcout << "Number of bytes read: " << numBytesRead << endl;
   // wcout << "Message: " << buffer << endl;
} else {
   // wcout << "Failed to read data from the pipe." << endl;
}

// Close our pipe handle
CloseHandle(pipe);


system("pause");
return 0;

return 0;
 }
```

However, when I run it, the (pipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) is true.
Debugging shows that DWORD err = GetLastError(); has the value 2, although the server is running.
Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can find many examples on the net. Search for named pipe example c++.
For example: http://www.avid-insight.co.uk/2012/03/introduction-to-win32-named-pipes-cpp/

Comment: Hi jmihalicza, thanks for your reply! I edited my entry post now. Do you know what I have to do now?

Comment: `2` is `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. Use an absolute path or make sure cwd of the process matches file location.